# Python 3.3 Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

```
myfile = ["no", "yes", "dog", "dog", "dog", "male"], ["no", "orange", "symbol", "church"]


my_Male_Dict = {}
for word in myfile:
    if word in my_Male_Dict:
       my_Male_Dict[word] += 1
    else:
        my_Male_Dict [word] = 1
print (my_Male_Dict['dog'])
```

This code shows me how to determine the number of times the word dog appears in my list. 
BUT, how do i determine if the word 'yes' and 'no' appear at the same time in my list?

I'm using this to understand a bigger list, in which factors like both age and location need to be determined, but i'm starting with two small lists so I can understand. Totally lost and new to python.

Comment: could you make an example of what it should look like? eg. what is the desired print output?

Comment: hi there, basicsally i want a number, 1 or 2 or 3 for the times it appears. thanks.

Answer (score -2):

The first line of your code

```
myfile = ["no", "yes", "dog", "dog", "dog", "male"], ["no", "orange", "symbol", "church"]
```

will actually point `myfile` to a tuple of lists, due to the comma between the two lists; when you iterate through it, each `word` will be a list.

If you want to know whether a word appears in the dictionary you create, you can simply use

```
word in myDict
```

which will check through the keys of the dictionary and return whether or not `word` is included (you can also check for `word in aList`).